# Writing data to cells using an initial value

Tags: vba, excel

could I get help, I am trying to write data into cells in a spread sheet, using an initial value, then adding a specific increment until it reaches a maximum value also specified. I have included an example below. Thank you.

Min: 0.5
Max: 1.5
Increment: 0.1

wrote the code below, but it runs infinitely... 
sub IncrementValue()
    Dim iMin, iMax, inc, x As Single

```
iMin = Range("A1").Value
iMax = Range("A2").Value
Inc = Range("A3").Value

Range("B1").Value = iMin
x = 1

Do
x = x + 1
Range("B" & x).Value = Range("B" & x - 1).Value + Inc
Loop Until Range("B" & x).Value = iMax
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you also tried something already or are you just dumping your requirements here?

Comment: nope...worked as hard as i can on it... this is not a requirement.. just a case scenario..

Comment: @ugo please clarify. show a sample

Comment: Well, you say what you want to have and wait for someone to code it up for you without cost or investment from your side. That's what I would call "dumping your requirements".

Comment: Hi mehow, i've got cells that are labelled: Max, Min, increments. What I've done is create a userform and in the userform i have created 3 Text-Boxes all linking to my cell locations in my spreadsheet. When the user enters values into the 3 categories (min, max & increment), it transfers to the spreadsheet and populates the sheet based on the increment and not exceeding the maximum.  For maximum, I could easily link the texbox to the cell location, but increments become hard. Thanks a lot...

Comment: what are cells locations, how is the population going to work? horizontally? vertically? more details needed

Comment: Think about doing a sum loop until you hit the max, IE x = x + inc

Comment: vertically, i am trying to make it look like: ActiveCell.Offset(0,0), then it continuously offsets downwards till it fills 5 cells.

Comment: I used a Do..Loop Until comment but it seems to be running infinitely, I have to escape all the time.. Any further ideas please

Comment: No one can help you without your code to help.

Comment: Here's the code....Cheers   Sub Loop()
Dim iMin, iMax, inc, x As Single

iMin = Range("A1").Value
iMax = Range("A2").Value
Inc = Range("A3").Value

Range("B1").Value = iMin
x = 1

Do
    x = x + 1
    Range("B" & x).Value = Range("B" & x - 1).Value + Inc
Loop Until Range("B" & x).Value = iMax

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillIncrementingSeries(rStart As Range, dMin As Double, dMax As Double, dIncr As Double)

    rStart.Value = dMin
    rStart.Resize(((dMax - dMin) / dIncr) + 1, 1).DataSeries xlColumns, xlDataSeriesLinear, , dIncr, dMax

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dick, here's one, but it runs infintely..Thank you..Sub Loop()
Dim iMin, iMax, inc, x As Single

iMin = Range("A1").Value
iMax = Range("A2").Value
Inc = Range("A3").Value

Range("B1").Value = iMin
x = 1

Do
    x = x + 1
    Range("B" & x).Value = Range("B" & x - 1).Value + Inc
Loop Until Range("B" & x).Value = iMax

End Sub

Comment: Change it to `Loop Until Range("B" & x).Value >= iMax` and it won't run infinitely. But I prefer my method.

Comment: Hi Dick, included the > sign, and it ran brilliantly, I think your method's quite good, but can't seem to be able to allocate cell addresses to it.. Its definitely a lot shorter... You've been brilliant..thanks a massive bunch...